# C - What is this syntax about? <<

Tags: c

what does this sybol means please?
"<<"
for example:
if (1 << var)

I want the name of the thing to study. Thank you.

Comment: Shame on the people that downvoted this to negative.  Discouraging questions from people that are learning, regardless of their level of understanding, is just plain stupid.

Comment: @Nathan (I didn't downvote, I actually upvoted to counter the downvote), but I can see how they thinkt hat this is too easy to just google...

Comment: Nathan: I would assume the question was downvoted because it was a duplicate. You can't search for symbols, so people can't find the answer, causing a new person to ask the exact same question every week.

Comment: @mathepic: Understood, but Google "<< c symbol" and see the results.  Beginners would not necessarily know that is an operator.

Comment: well, I didnt put the "symbol" at Google.
I searched for: "C <<" :u
thanks

Comment: Most search engines do not cope with non-alphanumeric search keys.  A wiser choice of search term would have been "C operators"; that will giver you a complete list of C operators to study.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shifts the bits in the integer 1 `var` positions to the left. So in effect it calculates 2 to the power of `var`.

See [the article on bit shifts on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_shift#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23_and_Java).

Answer (score 5):

That is a "left bit shift" operator.  In your example, it shifts 0000..00001 left "var" places.  So if var is 1, this is the same as "1 << 1" which shifts 0001 to 0010, which is 2.  If var was 2 the answer would be 0100 (4), etc.  If this isn't making sense, you'll need to read up on binary arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

That's the `left bitwise shift operator`.

The other `bitwise shift operator` is `>>`.

Answer (score 3):

The name is [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29).

Comment: +1 for referring Alan to a good resource (instead of whatever he is using) ... but maybe (just maybe, I don't believe it) the OP already has a copy of The C Programming Language.

Answer (score 3):

It is the left shift operator.

You might want to read about [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23_and_Java), and more specifically, [bitshift operators](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html).

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is a bit manipulation operator. Specifically `<<` performs left shift operation. This achieves the effect of multiplying the underlying value by power of 2.

More information could be found at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation