# How does << and >> operator works in C?

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    int x=5;
    printf("%d%d%d \n",x,x<<2,x>>2);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - What is this syntax about? <<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008871/c-what-is-this-syntax-about)

Answer (score 6):

`<<` and `>>` are the left and right shift operators, respectively.

These operators apply a bitwise shift to the left operand; the number of positions to shift is determined by the right operand.

In this example, we have three expressions: `x`, `(x << 2)`, and `(x >> 2)`.

For `x = 5`, the values of these expressions are:

```
Expr.     Dec. Value  Binary Value (Top 24 bits (all zero) ommitted)
x         5           00000101
x << 2    20          00010100
x >> 2    1           00000001
```

Notice that a left shift of one position effectively multiplies an unsigned int by 2; similarly, right shift divides an unsigned integer by 2. Also, whether the shift is arithmetic or logical (i.e. sign sensitive) is implementation dependent.

Comment: thnx a lot....my all doubts r cleared...thnx...

Answer (score 4):

They are left shift and right shift operators. [Bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: But how does it work on this progrm????

Answer (score 0):

`<<` shifts to the left and `>>` to the right. So in your example `x>>2` throws away the last two bits of the 5 (101 in binary). That would be 1.

`5<<2` is 20 (10100 in binary).

Answer (score 0):

Those are logical shift operators, with `<<X` meaning Left Shift x times, and `>>X` meaning Right Shift x times.

If you have a number like 14, it is stored as a the series of bits "00001110". When you left shift this number 1 time, the stored bit sequence changes to "00011100", and you get the number 28. Shifting a number left is the same as multiplying it by 2, while shifting it right is the same as dividing by 2. In this example, any digits on the left side that would get pushed into a "9th" spot simply disappear since only 8 bits are available. The same rules apply for the right shift.

Answer (score 0):

`x<<y` means x*2^y (^ meaning "to the power of") and `x>>y` means x/2^y. They are well-defined only for positive `x`, only for `y` smaller than the width of the type of `x` in bits, and if `x` is signed, only when the result does not overflow.

Answer (score 0):

These are basically bitwise shift operators.

The left shift operator causes the bit pattern in the first operand to be shifted to the left by the number of bits specified by the second operand.
The value of a left-shift expression (x << y) is x * (2^y)

00010111 LEFT-SHIFT by 1 = 00101110

The right shift does the same thing but shifts the bit pattern to the right.
The value of a right-shift expression x >> y is x / (2^y)

00010111 RIGHT-SHIFT by 1 = 00001011