# How LEFT SHIFT and RIGHT SHIFT with binary 1 work?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift, shift, pic32

I know that `(10001010<<2) = 00101000`

And that `(10001010>>2) = 00100010`

How to shift when I have only one bit like this
`(1<<5) and (1>>5)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please let me know how does << and >> operator works in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739664/please-let-me-know-how-does-and-operator-works-in-c)

Comment: `(10001010<<2) = 00101000` --> No.  In C, the value to be shifted is at least 15 bits/signed or 16 bits/unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `1` in C is `int`, which is always larger than 1 bit.

Note that right-shifting a signed quantity is implementation-defined, but I guess most would give 0 since there's just a single 1 present and it's gone after the first bit shift.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you do ( 010101 << 1 ) then it will consider "010101" as a decimal number and not a binary.  The notation "0bxxx" tells the compiler that your number is binary ( 0b010101 ).
For a single bit (your question), 1 decimal = 1 binary so you can use 1.  However ( 1 >> anything ) should give you 0 all the time as you seem to know.

If you want to shift left, then this condition will return TRUE :

```
if( 8 == (1 << 3))
```

because (0b0001 << 3) = 0b1000 = 8